# Attaching hashtag to URL with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to build an ajax site without sacrificing SEO. My question is:
If I have link on my page like this:

```
   <a href="http://example.com/cats" id="cats">Cats</a>
   <a href="http://example.com/dogs" id="dogs">Dogs</a>
```

...when each link is clicked I would like to update the address bar with the corresponding hashtag. So, if "Cats" link is clicked the current location will be http://example.com/#cats and I can use this to show my ajax content. If javascript is off or user is search engine, they will go directly to /cats

Comment: Just two notes: 1) That isn't called a "hashtag" (which is Twitter jargon for something totally unrelated); it's called a fragment identifier or anchor identifier (see the HTML spec). 2) You shouldn't have a # symbol in an element's id, i.e. it should be id="cats", which will correspond to /some-url#cats.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can change the `location.hash` property, it will change the current anchor identifier without navigating away form the page, for example you could:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/cats" id="cats" class="ajaxLink">Cats</a>
<a href="http://mysite.com/dogs" id="dogs" class="ajaxLink">Dogs</a>
```

Then:

```
$('.ajaxLink').click(function (e) {
  location.hash = this.id; // get the clicked link id
  e.preventDefault(); // cancel navigation

  // get content with Ajax...
});​
```

Comment: WOW! I didn't know it was this easy. Now I can make all my future sites in ajax and still get my site crawled and indexed! :D

Comment: Only one thing though, if the user bookmarks this URL or clicks to it from another site, id doesn't return the current hash. It returns empty. Is there a solution to this? How can I check for the hash onload as well as onclick?

Comment: You just have to check the value of the `location.hash` property when the page loads, it will contain the identifier, including the `#` symbol, e.g.: `if (location.hash == '#dogs') { /*...*/ }`

Comment: sorry if it's a stupid question but why aren't the links something like `href="#cats"` or `href="#dogs"`. Can't you use the `href` to change the `location.hash` property? It seems less redundant than having also an `id`...

Answer (score 16):

Google will index a hash if it has an exclamation mark in the form: `#!dogs`

It then assumes that these are AJAX-oriented:

- [Google's FAQ about AJAX](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=174993)
- [Google's guide on how to make AJAX website crawlable](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set the window.location.href without reloading the page in javascript for security   reasons.

From what I've seen some people are saying Google will index # urls but they will be not considered separate pages and I think that is not what you want. I also have very little experience with SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Although simplicity is best, but if you just want to automate this process or make it genericise then you can use this lite plugin [jquery.hashTag.js](https://github.com/arpitremarkable/jquery.hashTag.js)

```
$('a').hashTag({
    source: function() {
      return $(this).attr('id');
    }
  });
```

Just put this snippet inside $(document).ready.

It will do rest of the work itself.
Like auto clicking on the link whose id was provided as the hash.

Answer (score -1):

BenMills, noone mentioned location.href, it's about location.hash which does not require page reload.