# AJAX and how to change address bar (?aaa=ggg)

Tags: javascript, ajax

i use Javascript(AJAX) and want to change the addressbar
Ex: http://mywebsite.com to http//mywebsite.com?web=info

Comment: Do you really know what [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming\)) is?

Answer (score 3):

you can not change the url without the page actually redirecting.  You can however append a hashtag to the url.

http://mywebsite.com to http://mywebsite.com#something

See this question on StackOverflow.

[Attaching hashtag to URL with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366481/attaching-hashtag-to-url-with-javascript)

Comment: No, i don't want to change hash, just ?web=info

Comment: @jhanifen : a "hashtag"?  Isn't that something used in twitter?  I believe in URLs that is called an anchor

Comment: Well obviously twitter has made the term hashtag associated with a tweet.  But #something in a url is also referred to as a hashtag.

Comment: @Snoob - You can not add ?web=info to the url without the page actually changing.  If you don't mind the page changing then @Hogan's answer below is correct.

Comment: This isn't true anymore, at least in webkit (and others as they evolve), see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3849758/what-is-this-technology-facebook

Comment: If you are only supporting "Good" browsers then that is definitely a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want ajax just do this:

```
window.location = "http://mywebsite.com?web=info";
```